# How to implement PassportJS Oauth (facebook/Google) authentication in Postman? I am Using NodeJS with PassportJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, passport.js

**I can't access `req.user` when i send get/post or any request from Postman.** I want to build API using Postman.
Its working fine in browser. I have 2 routes. The first route hits the Facebook and the second route is for callback.

```
router.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook"));
router.get(
  "/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    successRedirect: "/api/auth/current",
    failureRedirect: "/api/auth/facebook",
  })
);
```

The /current route is just sending  `res.send(req.user)`

This is my Server.js

```
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");

const { mongoose } = require("./db/mongoose");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const api = require("./api/index");

const app = express();

// bodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

// Cookie session
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey],
  })
);

// passport initialization
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./utils/passport");

//Cors
app.use(cors());

//API route

app.use("/api/", api);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am using passport.serialize and passport.desearlize to access the id from Cookie

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});
```

What should i do to get req.user when making API using Postman. Please help I am Newbie

Comment: Please show the code where you added the fb passport strategy

Comment: https://github.com/StackBeans/Review-App checkout the code